# predictive raster range goes beyond 0-1 for binomial data (package 'raster')

Tags: r, gis, raster, prediction, glm

I used the 'raster' package to make a map of probabilities with binomial response variable. The problem is that when I plot the results, my predictive raster values range from -15 to 5 as opposed to 0-1. I used the same code as in Hijmans, Elith. 2016. 'Species distribution modeling with R' (p.34). They get  probability range from 0 to 1 while I keep getting weird values. What am I am doing wrong? 
Here is reproducible example with the first 50 rows of my data.

```
install.packages("lme4")
install.packages("raster")
install.packages("rgdal")

library("lme4")
library("raster")
library("rgdal")

# my data
data = structure(list(colorSymbol = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), bio_2 = c(75L, 168L, 
57L, 127L, 120L, 100L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 94L, 102L, 102L, 89L, 
89L, 102L, 96L, 97L, 92L, 100L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 96L, 97L, 95L, 
97L, 105L, 96L, 92L, 96L, 97L, 97L, 88L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 99L, 
96L, 97L, 97L, 100L, 97L, 96L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 98L, 94L), 
bio_3 = c(24L, 36L, 32L, 57L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
31L, 33L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 32L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 34L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 34L, 31L, 32L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 32L, 32L)), .Names = c("colorSymbol", "bio_2", 
"bio_3"), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
# model
bio2 = data$bio_2
bio3 = data$bio_3
colorSymbol = data$colorSymbol
model = glm(colorSymbol ~ bio2 + bio3, family = binomial)
# predictors
w = getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=10)
rasstack <- stack(w$bio2, w$bio3)
p <- raster::predict(rasstack, model)
plot(p)
```

Here's what I get: [image: prediction raster]

I searched online thoroughly but can't get what's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

By default `predict` gives you results on the *link* (logit) scale rather than the *response* (probability) scale: just use `type="response"` to get predictions on the probability scale.

```
p <- raster::predict(rasstack, model, type="response")
plot(p)
```

[image]

Comment: While the sentiment is appreciated, StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.